# Battery Corrosion

Tags: battery, car, corrosion

I just got my car serviced 2 1/2 months ago.  Today my car wouldn't start and found out i have massive corrosion around the connectors and it looks like the connectors have been eaten thru so it doesn't connect anymore but the battery still has charge.

So my question is, do you think the corrosion was there when I got my car serviced?
How long does it take for a massive corrosion to build up?

Answer (score 1):

Battery terminals normally [consists of lead posts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_terminal#Automotive_battery_terminals) so my guess is that it would take forever for them to get eaten.

However the connectors are made from other materials. Depending on the material used, they can corrode differently.

I imagine 2 months is probably not enough for such intense corrosion to build up. But if your battery is covered by a plastic cover, perhaps service could easily miss such corrosion happening. My guess would be that corrosion was probably there longer. See this thread also about [corrosion on battery terminals](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15120/what-causes-battery-terminal-corrosion)