# How can I prevent, slow or reduce white corrosion build-up on my battery?

Tags: electrical, battery, corrosion

I have an 02 Civic SiR (Canadian model) with a maintainable battery.  I check and refill the electrolytes every few months with distilled water.  The battery is about 4 years old.

I use a Battery Tender (float charger) with a wiring harness installed on the battery to easily attach the charger, which I do most nights in winter.  I only have outdoor parking and batteries lose voltage very quickly when it's -30C!

I get white corrosion build-up around the terminals and the tie-down bracket that seems to accumulate rather quickly.  I cleaned it only a few weeks ago and it's already built-up again.

Does charging increase the rate of accumulation?  Does the fact that it's a maintainable battery affect this in any way?  How can I prevent or reduce this?

[image: battery with corrosion buildup]

Comment: Once thoroughly clean a good coating with petroleum jelly is something that I find works.

Comment: @SolarMike: where, specifically, do apply the jelly?  And how much do I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes battery terminal corrosion?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15120/what-causes-battery-terminal-corrosion)

Comment: On the battery terminals... a quick google search may be effective : https://www.rd.com/home/5-car-battery-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: as @SolarMike say baking soda or soda is good for stopping the corrosion,but you can use dish whashing soap and water too as this is slightly alkaline and will neutralize the acid that creates the corrosion in the fist place after this use battery grease on the poles and the metall.

Comment: @trondhansen I did my apprenticeship as a vehicle electrician... But you could direct your comment to the OP...

Answer (score 1):

> I check and refill the electrolytes every few months with distilled water.

There's no earthly reason for you to need to do that.

> I use a Battery Tender (float charger) with a wiring harness installed on the battery to easily attach the charger, which I do most nights in winter.

Oh, wait, *I take that back.*

The problem is, your alternator is a 3-stage charger that knows exactly how to charge your battery without overcharge.

Your battery tender is a cheapie (let me guess, Canadian Tire) that just blasts energy into your battery without the slightest clue or care of overcharging.

See, the battery doesn't need to be *charged*; it's already 100% charged when you park it. What the battery needs is to **be warm**.  Warm batteries have much more cranking amps than cold ones.  What your battery "tender" is doing is **heating the battery, *by overcharging it***.

Hence, all the splashing.

And the problem is, you're adding water back in, but *what's coming out* is obviously not *merely* water.  The overcharging is causing it to gas off and sputter up the essential chemicals from the battery itself, i.e. the acid.  I bet it neutralizes very nicely with baking soda, yes?  It's battery acid.  *That belongs inside the battery, not splashing out*.

You're needing to add water because you're boiling off water (and sputtering out acid to boot) **because you're overcharging it**.  And what makes you think the battery tender works is the side-effect of overcharging: heating the battery.

**If you want a battery tray heater, then get a battery tray heater**.

*By the way, if that was not a maintainable battery, the water still would have boiled off, but you would not have been able to replace it. You're not allowed to overcharge non-maintainable batteries!*

Comment: Are you not familiar with battery tenders?  They're **specifically** designed to maintain a charge **without** overcharging.

Comment: @autobottodoggo So they say.  I certainly sympathize with trusting that marketing claim, but given the stack of evidence here, the most likely explanation here is that one is not meeting its promises.  Does your battery behave like this when you *don't* use the tender, i.e. in summer?

Comment: I didn't take note of it in summer, but I'll keep an eye on it this year.

Comment: @harper-reinstate-monica: I've had my battery disconnected from the charger for several weeks now and I'm still getting same rate of build-up.

Comment: @autobottodoggo Thanks for following up.  I will change my mind on that particular topic.  However, as to your problem that is a mystery.  Perhaps the battery is having problems (4 years seems a *little* early) -- or could the alternator be overcharging the battery??

Comment: I make mostly short trips, however, I've been doing almost no driving for the past few weeks because of the pandemic (I work from home).  It's been parked except for 2 or 3 short trips and off the charger the whole time.  I checked on it today and I could tell the voltage was low by the lagginess in the electric locks.

Comment: @autobottodoggo Well 3 weeks shouldn't kill the battery.  Maybe there's a voltage drain, or maybe the battery is at end of life.  But the latter is a chicken/egg question, one would expect it to be weak since so much of its sulfuric acid is coming out the terminals...