# Do battery corrosion pads really work?

Tags: battery, maintenance

I see various sources suggesting that chemically-treated felt pads be placed under battery terminals, to reduce or eliminate corrosion - like these:

[image: two felt pads - red and green]

Usually either red/black or red/green.

Do these anti-corrosion pads or washers actually work? Is this snake oil? If I place some oil or anti-corrosion chemical around the battery terminal, will that achieve the same effect, or do the pads actually help?

e.g. [here is an AutoZone article claiming they really make a difference](https://www.autozone.com/diy/battery/clean-car-battery-corrosion)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my experience these DO work.  They contain corrosion inhibiting chemicals that help keep the terminals from building up the greenish-white powder that is commonly seen on unmaintained battery terminals.

While I have no definitive studies of my own to prove they work, my anecdotal story is that they are an easy and inexpensive way to avoid corrosion.

Comment: I would tend to agree with you. I think even if they don't absorb anything, they still provide a barrier between the post and the top of the battery, which will allow them an easy way to get rid of any corrosion which might form. Also, as you state, they're cheap.

Comment: I would also suggest buying the packet that includes a packet of protective grease you place on the battery terminals.  This is an added layer of protection.  I found these at AutoZone as well.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response. It would be nice if there were some full studies with data, but I'm glad if they are successfully working for other car owners.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the felt washers don't help as much as the corrosion inhibiting chemicals that you can spray or paint onto the connectors and exposed wires. But I do still use them, along with inhibitor that I paint on. The coatings are pretty messy, but car batteries generally are pretty messy so I don't know how much that matters. If you use the coatings you might want to also use terminal caps to minimize how much dirt ends up clinging to the coating.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience over 50 years, battery corrosion on my early vehicles lead me to try the felt pads. Never had any corrosion whatsoever since I started using them